# Traefik configuration domain.com ---> server100:8080/test/foo

Tags: routes, backend, traefik

is it possible to route request from domain.com to a specific server with a predifned path like  domain.com --> http://server.local:8080/test/foo ?

I try this, but it seems not working:

http:
services:
my-service:
loadBalancer:
servers:
- url: "http://server.local:8080/test/foo"

Regards
David

Answer (score 0):

Yes its absolutely possible. You have to use the appropriate middleware.
For kubernetes we use this

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: i-redirect-stuff
  namespace: dev

spec:
  redirectRegex:
    regex: ^https://(www.)?firstDomain.com/(.*)
    replacement: https://secondSubdomain.secondDomain.com
    permanent: true
```

More information [docs link](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/redirectregex)

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but this is not what i want.
I want to route from externaldomain.com  to internal server like http://server:8080/foo/test

so it should route and add also a path "foo/test" to the request